# Force Download of .mp3 or .zip files on Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

After a user fills out an email verification form (which is submitted via AJAX), I want to force a download to start in the current browser window if the AJAX call response is successful.

The email verification form looks like:

```
<form id="form_download_email" method="POST" action="music_email_verification.php">
    <input id="download_email" type="text" tabindex="1" /> <br/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="download_email_button">
        Download!
    </a>
</form>
```

The js/jquery once the "download_email_button" is clicked looks like this:

```
$("#download_email_button").click(function() {

    var action = $("#form_download_email").attr('action');
    var form_data = {email: $("#download_email").val()};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 'success'){    
                window.location.assign('URL to .mp3 or ZIP');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The response=='success' block gets entered, and for now the only solution I found to force a download of a file without launching a pop up window (through window.open - which gets blocked by Chrome anyway), is to use window.location.assign as shown above. Is this the correct way of going about forcing a file download through JS??

However, using the window.location.assign method I can only download 1 file, and if I try to put in two lines with two mp3s, it doesn't work. AKA:

```
window.location.assign('http://song1.mp3');
window.location.assign('http://song2.mp3');
```

I do not want the user to have to click on another link after submitting the form to have to download the .mp3/.zip, I want to try to do it all in JS/jQuery.

The final method I thought about was on response=='success' to have the browser click on two hidden  tags on the document that had their href pointing to the mp3s. However, it seems that "The issue is that you can't trigger a link's default action via a click" with jquery, just the onclick attribute.

Should I be doing this with js? If there is no way to do this, should I try something like PHP?

Any suggestions on the current way I do it or recommendations on how to download multiple mp3 files would be helpful!

Comment: Open a new tab to the download perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an iframe for each url to download and set the iframe's source to files url :)

```
var 
    urls = ['url_1.mp3', 'url_2.mp3', /* ... , */ 'url_N.mp3'],

    doLoad = function(url){
        $("<iframe />")
            .css("display", "none")
            .bind("load", function(e){
                this.src == url && $(this).remove();
            })
            .attr("src", url)
            .appendTo($(document.body));
    };

for( var i=0; i < urls.length; i++ ) {
    doLoad( urls[i] );
}
```

Comment: I assume this will this also work if I throw 1 or more .zips as the urls?

Comment: @alex: i think so :), contrary to zip files there can be problem with mp3 files if browser tries to play them instead of saving on disk :).